# Parentheses for three lines of code

Tags: equations

I need to transfer the equation below into a latex. Unfortunately, my code does work as intended:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align}

 C(t) = (1-\alpha) (\theta+\lambda) &\cdot \left[K(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty} \left(W(v)-G(v)e^{\beta(v-t)}\right) e^{-\int_{t}^{v}\left(r(u)+\beta\right) du}dv \\
 & \quad -\int_{t}^{v}T(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{v} \left(r(u)+\beta \right)du}\left[1-e^{\beta(v-t)}
\right]dv \\
& \quad P(t)\left(M(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty}\dot{M}(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{\infty}i(u)du}dv\right)\right]

\end{align}
```

In particular, I cannot find a solution for the large parentheses and how to order the three lines correctly. 
Any help and suggestions are highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which large parentheses? The outer brackets? Is it really a matrix?

Answer (score 5):

*(off topic: pay attention on integral limits)*

I'd write like this:

```
\begin{align*}
C(t) = (1-\alpha) (\theta+\lambda) 
&\cdot \Bigl[K(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty} \bigl(W(v)-G(v)e^{\beta(v-t)}\bigr) e^{-\int_{t}^{v}(r(u)+\beta) du}dv \\
&\quad -\int_{t}^{v}T(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{v} (r(u)+\beta )du}\bigl(1-e^{\beta(v-t)}\bigr)dv \\
&\quad + \frac{1}{P(t)}\bigl(M(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty}\dot{M}(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{\infty}i(u)du}dv\bigr)\Bigr]
\end{align*}
```

Don't use too much `\left \right`. Instead, you can use `\bigl \bigr`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I propose these variants: two with another alignment point, and a `multline*` environment, which fits on two  lines (with the `geometry` package), and looks better, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
C(t) = (1-\alpha) (\theta+\lambda)
\cdot \biggl[K(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty} \bigl(W(v)-G(v)e^{\beta(v-t)}\bigr) e^{-\int_{t}^{v}(r(u)+\beta) du}dv \\
 -\int_{t}^{v}T(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{v} (r(u)+\beta )du}\bigl(1-e^{\beta(v-t)}\bigr)dv \\
{}+ \frac{1}{P(t)}\bigl(M(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty}\dot{M}(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{\infty}i(u)du}dv & \bigr)\biggr]
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
C(t) = (1-\alpha) (\theta+\lambda)
\cdot \biggl[K(t)&+\int_{t}^{\infty} \bigl(W(v)-G(v)e^{\beta(v-t)}\bigr) e^{-\int_{t}^{v}(r(u)+\beta) du}dv \\
 &-\int_{t}^{v}T(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{v} (r(u)+\beta )du}\bigl(1-e^{\beta(v-t)}\bigr)dv \\
& + \frac{1}{P(t)}\bigl(M(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty}\dot{M}(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{\infty}i(u)du}dv\bigr)\biggr]
\end{align*}

\begin{multline*}
C(t) = (1-\alpha) (\theta+\lambda)
\cdot \biggl[K(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty} \bigl(W(v)-G(v)e^{\beta(v-t)}\bigr) e^{-\int_{t}^{v}(r(u)+\beta) du}dv \\
 -\int_{t}^{v}T(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{v} (r(u)+\beta )du}\bigl(1-e^{\beta(v-t)}\bigr)dv
 + \frac{1}{P(t)}\bigl(M(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty}\dot{M}(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{\infty}i(u)du}dv\bigr)\biggr]
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: although the third variant is the most compact, i think the second variant expresses the structure most clearly.

Answer (score 3):

In Sigur answer, the key point is

> Don't use too much \left \right. Instead, you can use \bigl \bigr.

and the proposed solution is perfect.

Nevertheless, if you really want to keep the three-lines format, you need the `\left[...\right]` structure and could use :

```
\begin{equation*}
 C(t) = (1-\alpha) (\theta+\lambda) \,\left[
\begin{aligned}
 &K(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty} \left(W(v)-G(v)e^{\beta(v-t)}\right) e^{-\int_{t}^{v}\left(r(u)+\beta\right) du}dv \\
 & -\int_{t}^{v}T(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{v} \left(r(u)+\beta \right)du}\left[1-e^{\beta(v-t)} \right]dv \\
 & P(t)\left(M(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty}\dot{M}(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{\infty}i(u)du}dv\right)
\end{aligned}
\right]
\end{equation*}
```

That is to say : (i) you have a single equation (iii) the alignment is only permormed betwen the braces (ii) left alignment is  achieved by using a single `&` at the left most side in the `aligned` environment.

**Edit:** replaced figure

[image]

Comment: Is the image exactly the output of your code? On the left, looks like no math mode.

Comment: Another possibility is to right aligned just removing the `&`. It is not what OP asked but could be helpful.

Comment: The previous figure was obtained with the ``standalone`` without loading any fonts. I edited the my post with the "correct" results with ``article`` and LM fonts.

Comment: Careful, it looks like you neglected to invert `P(t)` and introduced some typos in the limits of integration.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Jhor's answer, but aesthetically I like aligning on the operators for the three lines:

```
C(t) = (1-\alpha) (\theta+\lambda)
\left[
  \begin{aligned}
    K(t) &+\int_{t}^{\infty} \left(W(v)-G(v)e^{\beta(v-t)}\right) e^{-\int_{t}^{v}(r(u)+\beta) du}dv \\
    & -\int_{t}^{\infty}T(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{v} (r(u)+\beta )du}\left[1-e^{\beta(v-t)}\right]dv \\
    & + \frac{1}{P(t)}\left(M(t)+\int_{t}^{\infty}\dot{M}(v)e^{-\int_{t}^{v}i(u)du}dv\right)
  \end{aligned}
\right]
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Of cousre, it is what I would do. But I tried to stick to te OP aims, as I understood it... :-)

Comment: This looks like [Bernards second variant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437667/123129).

Comment: @dexteritas Not so, since the brackets surround all three lines as in OP's figure of what he wanted to reproduce.

Comment: @pjs Ah, ok. I overlooked that.